# How to Send Internal table to SAP Spool using ABAP Class Method

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I want to use ABAP class and it's method to send internal table to a spool.
Please help.

I don't want to use any Function Module, because it is strictly prohibited for my software.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the class `CL_RSPO_SPOOL_HANDLE`. It provides an object-oriented interface to spool jobs.

(Internally, it is just a thin wrapper around different function-modules from the function-group SPOX)